# Storing any type or struct in an std::map

Tags: c++, events, dictionary

I'm writing a topic-based publish/subscribe system in C++.  My generic "Event" class has three parts:

1. Event Type (std::string)
2. Entity ID (unsigned int) - this is for the game engine
3. Event Data (std::map<std::string, ???>)

To populate the "Event Data" map, I need to be able to store any data type or struct, like int, string, or Vector3 (struct), to give some examples.  How can I do this?  Or, maybe there is a better way to do this altogether...

On an unrelated note, is it better to use a char* or a string for event types and data names?

Comment: Aways use `std::string`.

Comment: Why?  (Not questioning your judgement, I just want to know)

Comment: It's easier, standard, and prevents bugs. There may be some edge cases in which a char* is better, but you'll almost never have a reason good enough to justify using one over an std::string.

Comment: carleeto just explained to me why I shouldn't use a char* here, but okay.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tried [boost:any](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/doc/html/any/s02.html) ?

For your event types, why are you using a string?
std::maps are stored sorted from lower to higher key value. 
This means that internally, you're going to be sorting strings.
Try and keep it as simple as possible to start off with. Use an enum, which should make your maps that much faster, especially given they're going to be the foundation of a notification system.

Finally, you don't want to use char*, because the map will not work as you expect:

```
char* key1 = "Hi";
char* key2 = "Hi";
unsigned int id;
std::map< char* ,unsigned int > mymap;
mymap.insert( std::pair<char*,unsigned int>( key1, id ) );
mymap.insert( std::pair<char*,unsigned int>( key2, id ) ); //you've just created a duplicate entry
```

The reason is that key1 and key2 will have different addresses, even though they're the same string.

Comment: I'd rather not use an enum, if I don't have to.  And no, I've never used Boost.  I'll give it a try, though.

Comment: Oh, yeah, that makes sense.  I'll switch to an enum if I think I need the slight performance boost ;)

Comment: If you want a textual description of your type, you can always use a function along the lines of std::string GetDescription( EventType t );

Comment: To get an idea of the difference in performance, there is nothing like a test. Use a map of strings and compare it to a map of integers.